# Linq to Entities Union generating inner join to unioned table

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I'm running in to an issue that's baffling me.  When I try to union two tables together, the query to the second table is generating an inner join back to the the first table.  The whole point of using the union is to return a result if the record exists in either table, but this inner join is causing it to fail if a record is in the second table, but not the first.

I did some testing on a much smaller scale to see if I'm going crazy, and that doesn't seem to be the case.

I have two tables, OrderDetails and OrderDetailHistories.  Back story: After a certain period of time records are removed from the details table and put into the histories table.  The fields and everything are exactly the same.  In fact, this is the entity for OrderDetailHistories:

```
public partial class OrderDetailsHistory : OrderDetail { }
```

So, to start out, I wrote a little test query that's a pretty good representation of what I'm seeing.

```
var test = this.context.OrderDetails
    .Select(x => x.Descr)
    .Union(this.context.OrderDetailsHistories
        .Select(x => x.Descr))
    .Where(x => x == "wat")
    .ToList();
```

Which generates this query:

```
SELECT 
[Distinct1].[C1] AS [C1]
FROM ( SELECT DISTINCT 
    [UnionAll1].[Descr] AS [C1]
    FROM  (SELECT 
        [Extent1].[Descr] AS [Descr]
        FROM [dbo].[OrderDetails] AS [Extent1]
        WHERE N'wat' = [Extent1].[Descr]
    UNION ALL
        SELECT 
        [Extent3].[Descr] AS [Descr]
        FROM  [dbo].[OrderDetails_History] AS [Extent2]
        INNER JOIN [dbo].[OrderDetails] AS [Extent3] ON ([Extent2].[Order_No] = [Extent3].[Order_No])
        WHERE N'wat' = [Extent3].[Descr]) AS [UnionAll1]
)  AS [Distinct1]
```

Huh?  Why does that second select statement even reference the details table?  What happens when I use a concat?  Same thing.  Intersect?  Same inner join.  Okay, maybe instead of unioning first, then applying my condition, I can apply the conditions to each query, then just union the results.

How about this?

```
var query1 = this.context.OrderDetails.Where(x => x.Descr == "wat").Select(x => x.Descr);
var query2 = this.context.OrderDetailsHistories.Where(x => x.Descr == "wat").Select(x => x.Descr);
var result = query1.Concat(query2).ToList();
```

Generates almost the exact same query!  Does anyone know what's going on here?  Are my expectations just off?

If I throw a .ToList() at the end of the query1 and query2 statements above it works exactly like I'd expect, but then I lose my ability to do paging in sql and end up pulling down *far* too many records, when we're only displaying 10 per page.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what EF approach you are using, I suppose Code first. But anyways, you are using it wrong or you don't know how it works. When you inherit your `OrderDetailsHistory` class from `OrderDetail` then it says, that `OrderDetailsHistory` is always an `OrderDetail`.

So if you want to select all orders you can just query `OrderDetail` and there will be also all `OrderDetailsHistory` entities:

```
this.context.OrderDetails
    .Select(x => x.Descr)   
    .Where(x => x == "wat")
    .ToList();
```

It is also important to know how data are stored in your DB. You are using table per class aproach - read some articles about it (e.g. http://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/inheritance-mapping-strategies-with-entity-framework-code-first-ctp5-part-2-table-per-type-tpt ) to understand how it works, then you will also understand why all your queries look "so strange"...